# How to dynamically check CheckBoxes?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, checkbox

I'm generating CheckBoxes dynamically and I want to check them depending on which options should be selected.

I have the following XAML:

```
        <StackPanel>
            <StackPanel x:Name="ArmingPanel" />
        </StackPanel>
```

And the following code:

```
    private void AddCheckBoxes(OptionsVM options)
    {
        var converter = new FlagsEnumValueConverter();
        foreach (Arming arming in Enum.GetValues(typeof(Arming)))
        {
            if (arming != Arming.None)
            {

                var binding = new Binding()
                {
                    Path = new PropertyPath("Arming"),
                    Converter = converter,                        
                    ConverterParameter = arming
                };

                var checkBox = new CheckBox()
                                   {
                                       Content = arming.ToString(),
                                       IsChecked = (options.Options.Arming & arming) != Arming.None
                                   };

                checkBox.SetBinding(CheckBox.IsCheckedProperty, binding);
                ArmingPanel.Children.Add(checkBox);
            }
        }
    }
```

Depending on which flags have been set, the following should be set to `true` or `false`:

```
IsChecked = (options.Options.Arming & arming) != Arming.None
```

I can see this value being set correctly when I debug, but when the checkboxes are listed on the screen they're always unchecked.

How can I get them to be checked as expected?

Comment: The `IsChecked`-property is set by your binding.

Comment: Something tells me your binding is broken. You shouldn't set your IsChecked property manually if you're going to bind it to something.

Comment: As Matten said, `IsChecked` ist set by your `binding`immediately after you set it in code. Check your `FlagsEnumValueConverter` if it returns `Nullable<bool` to properly set that property. And why does the converter get the `arming` enum value as parameter, when it already gets it as value to convert.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In calling you `CheckBox` constructor you set `IsChecked`, which sets the `IsCheckedProperty` on the checkbox. You then set the `IsCheckedProperty` again with a `Binding`, so the first setting is overridden.

I suspect your issue is with the `Converter` and the `ConverterParameter` in the Binding

Answer (score -1):

**EDIT:** This isn't an asnwer to the OP's question, but I feel it deserves mentioning.

It appears that you're checking for enum flags, the proper boolean expression is:

`(options.Options.Arming & arming) == arming`

if this expression returns `true`, then `options.Options.Arming` contains the flag stored in `arming`

It is also important that your `enum Arming` members be defined correctly!

Comment: The OP says that the value is set correctly when he runs it in debug mode. But he sets a databinding to the property after manually setting it, which overrides the previously set "correct" value. So this `enum Arming` members are defined correctly.

Comment: We can't speak to the definition of `Arming` or the value of `Arming.None`, my "answer" should have been a comment, but it was too long.  And I should have made it clear that I'm not answering the real question here.

Comment: To the down vote, would you prefer that I just delete this?  Do you not feel that it's an important critique of the example code given?

Comment: I'm not the downvoter, but given that this wasn't the OP's issue, I'm not sure this post adds any value to the question. Whether you delete it or not depends on how valuable _you_ think this post is.

Comment: Yeah, I'll concede that the down vote is merited.  I'll edit to make my intention clear and hope that in the future the information is valuable to somebody.